# Stopping onclick from firing when onclientclick is false?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, asp.net-3.5, onclientclick

Is it possible to use the `onclientclick` property of a button to do a clientside check.  If the check returns `true`, then fire the `onclick` event.  If the clientside check returns `false`, don't fire the `onclick` event.

Is that possible?

**UPDATE:**

These 2 work:

```
Stops the form from submitting:
OnClientClick="return false;"
```

---

```
Allows the form to submit:
OnClientClick="return true;"
```

---

The next 2 do not work:

```
// in js script tag
function mycheck() {
    return false;
}

// in asp:button tag
OnClientClick="return mycheck();"
```

---

```
// in js script tag
function mycheck() {
    return true;
}

// in asp:button tag
OnClientClick="return mycheck();"
```

It submits the form both times.

Why is that?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You want to add `return` inside OnClientClick after a function is called. Otherwise, the button will post back even if function returns false.

```
<asp:button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" 
    OnClientClick="return checkValidation()" Text="Submit" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function checkValidation() {
        return confirm('Everything ok?');
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Your updated code work. You can test it by creating a new aspx (without master page). It might be something to do with your existing javascript code interfere with the mycheck function.

Comment: Haha! Yes, I was missing the `return` portion of my `OnClientClick`. Thank ya, thank ya!

Comment: This is not entirely accurate. Returning false simply prevents a postback.  The the onclick method is still fired on the server side, however its effects are not updated to the screen.   If you are using this to prevent say a database update, beware as the event would still fire.

Comment: @JSON ***If client doesn't communicate back with server, how does server trigger click event by itself.*** Please note that ***Http is Stateless***. What you mention is not possible unless you use Signal-R which is totally out of the question. *If you have a question, please create one; I'll happy to help you.*

Comment: @Win  Perhaps it depends on the type of server you are using.  I know for a facts that IIS is like this. I am using it right now and would prove it to you if I could.

Comment: @JSON As I said if you have question or doubt on how ASP.Net works, please create a new question. Please do not confuse the others with ***incorrect comments***; the answer has been tested by multiple developers, and upvoted 26 times as of today. Otherwise, please kindly delete your comments.

Comment: I'm using ASP .NET WebForms and I got burned by the UseSubmitBehavior="false" in the asp:button tag.  If this is false (default is true so not having it is true) then even if the OnClientClick event returns true such as OnClientClick="return true;" you will not postback so your client side event won't fire.  Once I removed UseSubmitBehavior, which is the same as setting it to true, I got the functionality described in this answer.

Answer (score 8):

Sure. If you use `return false` within your `OnClientClick` it will prevent any navigation from happening. So you're code would look like:

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" OnClientClick="if(!ValidatePage()) { return false;}" />
```

Comment: @oshirowanen I honestly don't remember exactly why you explicitly why you have to put `return false` in the `OnClientClick`. If I recall, it has to do with the encapsulation ASP.NET does around your code within the `OnClientClick` when it renders the actual HTML and Javascript.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can, In onclientClick  function call use `preventDefault()`

```
function onclientClickFun(e)
{
  if(!IsValidationSuccess)
 {
   e.preventDefault();
 }

}
```

**OR**

```
function onclientClickFun(e)
{
  if(!IsValidationSuccess)
 {
   return false;
 }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I came across this issue too.  Did not like to have to put the OnClientClick=return false on every linkbutton.  With a simple page it just easier to use an anchor and avoid asp filling the href in for you.

However this is not always possible.  So a Simple conclusion is just to inherit the LinkButton and add a variable like AutoPostBack.  if false then just override the output with the html or add the OnClientClick in.  I dont really like inline tags.

```
namespace My.WebControls {
    [ToolboxData("<{0}:LinkButton runat=server ID=btn></{0}:LinkButton>"), ParseChildren(true), ToolboxItem(true)]
    public class LinkButton : System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton {

         private bool _postback = true;
         [Bindable(true), Category("Behavior"), DefaultValue(true), Description("Gets or Sets the postback click behavior")]
         public bool AutoPostBack { get { return _postback; } set { _postback = value; } }


         protected override void Render(System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter writer) {
             if(!AutoPostBack){
                 this.OnClientClick = "return false";
             }
             base.Render(writer);
         }
    }
}
```

Many attributes should need to be handled in a ViewState but in this case I think we are good;

Answer (score 1):

**In the server page create the button**:

```
var button1 = new Button();  
button1.ServerClick += new EventHandler(button1_ServerClick);
button1.OnClientClick = SetJsForSaveBtn();
button1.Attributes.Add("UseSubmitBehavior", "false");
panel.Controls.Add(button1 );
```

//Contains the server code

```
private void saveBtn_ServerClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //do something if ClientClick returns true
}
```

//Contains the JS code for the page

```
LiteralControl js = new LiteralControl();
panel.Controls.Add(js);
js.Text =@"<script type='text/javascript'> 
$(document).ready(function(){
 function CheckValidationOnClient(){
   if(!ValidatePage()){
    return false;
   }
   else{
    return true;
   }
 };
});
</script>   ";

private string SetJsForSaveBtn()
{
  var jsfunc = @" return CheckValidationOnClient()";
  return jsfunc ;
}
```