# asp button prevent post back on javascript function return false

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am trying to prevent post back when javascript function returns false, but still post back occurs. I don't understand what I am missing in this code. I have searched in internet and they showed the same solution.

```
function chkMemName() {
            var valMemName = document.getElementById('<%= txtMemName.ClientID %>').value;

            if (valMemName.length == 0) {
                alert("member name missing!!!");
                txtMemName.focus();
                return false;
            }
        }

<label>MEM NAME</label>
<input type="text" maxlength="200" runat="server" id="txtMemName" autocomplete="off" />

<asp:Button ID="btnAddFamily" runat="server" OnClientClick="chkMemName(); return false;" ClientIDMode="Static" formnovalidate="formnovalidate" OnClick="btnAddFamily_Click" Text="ADD" />
```

Comment: You have a typo `chkMemName(): return false;` a colon there.

Comment: It was a typo I've edited my code. Still facing the same problem. Thank You!

Comment: You might want to try just `OnClientClick="return chkMemname();"`. You also may need to add `UseSubmitBehavior="false"`. See [Stopping onclick from firing when onclientclick is false?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19139747)

Comment: Fix typos and use `OnClientClick="return chkMemName();"`. **`return`** is important here.